# Avoiding assembly references when using IoC in multi layer app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, inversion-of-control

Quick question so I start in the right direction. I have a multi project solution with an MVC presentation layer. Currently this layer only knows about an IServices class library. Now if I want to use an IoC it seems like I will have to start adding references to all of the other projects in my solution in the MVC application so that I can configure the IoC.

Is this right or should each layer have its own IoC?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Someone* must load the .dll files, and *someone* be able to wire up the IoC.

Typically, the dll loading happens automatically and the IoC wiring happens in a nearly-hardcoded fashion.

You could load libraries dynamically: you can write code that tries to load each dll in a given folder and invoke some kind of `GetLibraryDescriptor` method. That method tells you that the library provides an implementation for, say, `ISomeInterface`. Now you can ask the dll to instantiate an object of that class it provides. You'd probably have to bridge this instantiation to the IoC. I believe that such a design is better suited for a service locator.

All this makes sense for shrink-wrap software, but I don't see many benefits for web software.

The only reason not to reference other libraries I see is to make sure nobody directly uses or access the code that is declared in there - a tedious task, a sometimes impossible goal that moves encapsulation to the wrong level. If your classes are well-encapsulated, it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: So is it generally accepted to just reference tha assemblies in the MVC project and wire up the IoC there?

Comment: Yes. You're not going to wake up say "today, I'll let the site run on DB2 instead of Cassandra", and if you do, it's not just replacing a dll.